# Cross account SNS topic

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-sns, aws-event-bridge

I have event rule configured in multiple accounts in same region which will get the events from cloudtrail and trigger the events. Since there are so many accounts I cannot configure SNS topic in each and every account and confirm the subscription manually.

How do I have a centralized SNS topic in one account so that the event rule will be sent from all the accounts to that one topic which can trigger the alerts? I haven't worked on this topic earlier and hoping to get some light.

Note: I want to achieve this in CF template.

Here is the cf template that I use.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: ''
Parameters:
  DestinationEmailAddress:
    Description: ''
    Type: String
    AllowedPattern: ^[A-Za-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z.-]+\.[A-za-z]{2,}$
  SNSTopicName:
    Description: The name of the SNS Topic.
    Type: String   
    AllowedPattern: ^[\w+=,.@/-]+$

Resources: 
  SnsTopic:
    Type: 'AWS::SNS::Topic'
    Properties:
      Subscription:
        - Endpoint: !Ref DestinationEmailAddress
          Protocol: email
      TopicName: !Ref SNSTopicName

  TopicPolicy:
    Type: AWS::SNS::TopicPolicy
    Properties: 
      PolicyDocument: 
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Sid: DefaultStatement
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - events.amazonaws.com
                - cloudwatch.amazonaws.com
                - config.amazonaws.com
                - cloudformation.amazonaws.com
            Action: 
              - "SNS:GetTopicAttributes"
              - "SNS:SetTopicAttributes"
              - "SNS:AddPermission"
              - "SNS:RemovePermission"
              - "SNS:DeleteTopic"
              - "SNS:Subscribe"
              - "SNS:ListSubscriptionsByTopic"
              - "SNS:Publish"
              - "SNS:Receive"
            Resource: !Ref SnsTopic
            Condition:
              StringEquals:
                "AWS:SourceOwner": 'AWS::'
          - Sid: AllowEventRuletoPosttoSNSTopic
            Effect: Allow
            Principal: 
              Service: "events.amazonaws.com"
            Action: "sns:Publish"
            Resource: !Ref SnsTopic
      Topics: 
        - !Ref SnsTopic

 
  EventRule:
    Type: 'AWS::Events::Rule'
    Properties:
      Name: ''
      Description: ''
      State: ENABLED
      Targets:
        - Arn: !Ref SnsTopic
          Id: SNSTopic
      EventPattern:
        source:
        - aws.kms
        detail-type:
        - AWS API Call via CloudTrail
        detail:
          eventSource:
          - kms.amazonaws.com
          eventName:
          - DisableKey
```

Comment: Your setup is not clear. Can you expand on it? Maybe provide some schematic illustration demonstrating what you want to achieve?

Comment: @Marcin I added the cf template. I need to deploy this in multiple accounts but I need to have a centralized SNS topic in one account.

Comment: Before you try doing that using CFN, can you do it manually using AWS Console, just to check what permissions and where are required to make that work?